# Old value - Select2 Multiple Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de recuperar las opciones selecionadas en un select2 multiple con old, pero tengo un problema, ya que no me devuelve solo las opciones seleccionadas sino también todas las opciones registradas, (lo demás funciona bien, guarda los datos seleccionados únicamente).

Aquí esta como devuelve todas las opciones, cuando únicamente había seleccionado dos de ellas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi tengo relacionado en mi modelo Profile y Specialty

```
public function especialidades()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Specialty::class);
}

public function profiles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Profile::class);
}
```

En mi controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
  public function edit($id)
{
    $perfil = Profile::with('especialidades')->where('id', auth()->user()->id)->get();    
    $especialidades = Specialty::all()->pluck('name', 'id');

    return view('profile.edit', compact('especialidades', 'perfil'));
}
```

y esto en la vista

```
<select class="select2bs4" name="especialidades[]" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="" style="width: 100%;">
    @foreach($especialidades as $id => $especialidades)
          <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ (in_array($id, old('especialidades', [])) || $perfil) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $especialidades }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que te devuelva lo que necesitas que solo son las etiquetas u opciones puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
@foreach ($especialidades as $especialidad)
    <option {{ collect(old('especialidades', $perfil->especialidades->pluck('id')))->contains($especialidad->id) ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $especialidad->id }}">{{ $especialidad(si tienes algun campo name o nombre iria despues de esto "->name") }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Con la clase collect nos ahorramos un foreach demás para esta ocasión, y solo preguntamos si especialidad contiene un id, si tiene entonces que lo seleccione

Comment: Probé de esa manera, pero me da el siguiente error "Property [especialidad] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: cuando haces un ddd($especialidades) en tu Controlador antes de redirigir a la ruta, que te arroja?

Comment: Me devuelve esto: Illuminate\Support\Collection {#520 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    2 => "Mecanica"
    3 => "Plomero"
    5 => "Carpintero"
  ]
}

Comment: Intenta traer todo sin el metodo pluck, y edito mi respuesta para que se ajuste, ya vi el error

Comment: ok, probé sin el pluck, pero igual error "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::especialidades does not exist." no se por que no esta tomandome la relacion

Comment: Al igual y tu llave foranea no esta de la manera correcta, puedes definirla como segundo parametro en tu modelo

Comment: De esta manera?: public function especialidades()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Specialty::class, 'profile_specialty', 'profile_id', 'specialty_id');
    }

Comment: si, pero tengo otra pregunta, cuando llamas al metodo pluck no es necesario que antes hagas un all(), simplemente con dejar pluck basta